# How can I disable the grouping of windows in Xfwm4 or Openbox?

Tags: linux, window-manager, xfce, manjaro, openbox

My system based on Manjaro groups windows from the same application into one entry in the taskbar. (As OSes seem to do these days) I tried with both Xfwm4 and Openbox to switch this feature off but none of them seem to have a setting for that.

Is this even a feature defined by the window manager?

Can anyone recommend a stacking window manager that lacks this 'feature' altogether or has the ability to switch it off?

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

Go to Window Buttons setting (right-click on panel > Panel > Panel Preferences > Items > select "Window Buttons" > Edit the currently selected item (a button on the right side)
In "Behaviour" > Window grouping => Never